# Discrete Knapsack Dynamic Programming Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

This is my first assignment dealing with Dynamic Programming and I'm finding it quite difficult.

Problem:

Given a knapsack of capacity W and n gold bars of weights [wt[0],..., wt[n - 1], find maximum number of gold bars that can fit into knapsack without repetition.

input:
line 1:(capacity knapsack(W)) (num gold bars(n))
line 2: weights of n gold bars (wt)

output: max weight (of gold bars) that can fit in knapsack of capacity W

My code:

```
import sys

def optimal_weight(W, wt):
    """Find max weight that can fit in knapsack size W."""
    # Create n nested arrays of 0 * (W + 1)
    max_vals = [[0] * (W + 1) for x in range(len(wt))]
    # Set max_vals[0] to wt[0] if wt[0] <= j
    max_vals[0] = [wt[0] if wt[0] <= j else 0 for j in range(W + 1)]
    for i in range(1, len(wt)):
        for j in range(1, W + 1):
            value = max_vals[i - 1][j]  # previous i @ same j
            if wt[i] <= j:
                val = (max_vals[i - 1][j - wt[i]]) + wt[i]
                if value < val:
                    value = val
                    max_vals[i][j] = value
                else:
                    max_vals[i][j] = value

    return max_vals[-1][-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    W, n, *wt = list(map(int, input.split()))
    print(optimal_weight(W, wt))
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? When I observe my ending max_vals, I am seeing that max_vals, as i increases, is only replacing increasingly smaller values (i - 1) in each nested list. In other words, as I continue iterating, fewer 0's are being replaced with the value of max_vals[i - 1][j]. Somewhat embarrassingly, I've been working on this for almost a week and can't figure it out. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LusJS5-AGo), aside from the class lecture video, has been my main point of reference. Dynamic programming is proving to be a pretty big challenge.

Comment: Is is allowed to pick a gold bar more than once?

Answer (score 3):

Trivially easy fix. Can't believe I missed it. Was just messing up with the else statements. Needed an extra.

```
        if value < val:
                value = val
                max_vals[i][j] = value
            else:
                max_vals[i][j] = value  # set to [i - 1][j]
        else:
            max_vals[i][j] = value   # set to [i - 1][j]
```